# Sql ddl get foreign key information

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, ddl

I'm doing a small web application that query a database using hibernate and show's in a jsp a table with the data received. For this I`m using DML statements that retreives the DB data.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
    query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
    List<Map<String, Object>> resultSetList = query.list();
```

The problem is when I have a table that has FK columns. What i need .. as I understood is a SQL DDL statement that retrieves the information about the FK columns in the table, information meaning .. the FK column, the name of the table if refers, and the column from the table it refers.

I`ve searched a lot but found nothing relevant, do you have any idea how should the ddl statement look like ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me !

```
 public Map<String, List<String>> getFKColumns(Session session, String tableName) {

    Map<String, List<String>> fkMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    try {
        Connection connection = session.connection();
        DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = meta.getImportedKeys(connection.getCatalog(), null, tableName);

        while (rs.next()) {

            List<String> fkValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            fkValues.add(rs.getString("PKTABLE_NAME"));
            fkValues.add(rs.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME"));

            fkMap.put(rs.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME"), fkValues);
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fkMap;
}
```